# bagof/3 giving weird results

Tags: collections, prolog, logic, swi-prolog

I'm working in goal/prolog (prolog swi 6.0.0) and have a situation where I would like to do the following: I have the following things in my belief base:

```
elevator([agent0,0,[]])
elevator([agent1,0,[]])
elevator([agent2,0,[]])
```

then execute the following query:

```
if bel(bagof(Elevator,elevator(Elevator),Elevators)) then insert (elevatorList(Elevators)).
```

However rather then the expected result of Elevators being

```
[[agent1,0,[]],[agent2,0,[]],[agent3,0,[]]]
```

the resulting list is

```
[Elevator/['.'(Agent0, '.'(0, '.'([], [])))]] [Elevator/['.'(Agent0, '.'(0, '.'([], []))),'.'(bidAgent, '.'(0, '.'([], [])))]] [Elevator/['.'(Agent0, '.'(0, '.'([], []))),'.'(bidAgent, '.'(0, '.'([], []))),'.'(agent1, '.'(0, '.'([], [])))]]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that everything is fine: You write substitutions in a very specific form. Instead of `Elevator = Term` you write `Elevator/Term`. Next, you probably use `write_canonical/1` instead of `writeq/1`.

Comment: I do see a problem in that first of all bagof creates a list containing the same evaluation multiple times rather then once, and what do the ( mean inside the list? Thirdly why does the list contain Elevator/ is there any way to get rid of that?

Comment: You need to show more of your code when the output is written.

Comment: if bel(bagof(Elevator,elevator(Elevator),Elevators)) then insert (elevatorList(Elevators)).  I directly inspect the believe base after that.

Comment: You need to show more than that.

Comment: This is placed dirrectly in the main module and the beliefs are placed straight into the belief base.

Comment: You use an `if...then` in Prolog?

Comment: This is in goal which relies on prolog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be useful. `bagof/3` seems to work fine on my end so it's likely that the problem lies in the `bel/1` predicate or the `if then insert` structure (is it some kind of operator or preprocessor like GRIPS?)

Comment: if then insert basically means that if the bel() is true then the values of insert are put in the belief base.